# delete mysql row by retrieving id PHP foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've created a foreach statement that echos out some stuff about all users registered, how do I make a button that deletes that user from the row? I've tried this:

```
$query = "
SELECT id
     , name
     , bname
     , email
     , address
     , agent
     , status
     , notes 
  FROM prospects
";

        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt ->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to run query. Tell the website owner!");
        }
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            echo "<tbody>
            <th>".$row['name']."</th>";
            echo "BLAH BLAH BLAH!";
            echo "<form method='post'><th><button type='submit' name='delete' class='btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon'>
                <i class='material-icons'>remove_circle_outline</i>
                <div class='ripple-container'></div>
            </button></th></tbody></form>";
        } $id = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM example");
        $id->execute();

        $result = $id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
                try {
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM example WHERE id='".$result."'";
                    $db->exec($sql);
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $sql . "<br />". $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
```

It returns this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion....

I know this is because I've grabbed the id and there is an array of ids that I've grabbed from the database? So how do I do delete a specific row when i click on the button?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify which element in array holds the id value.

**Try:**

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM example WHERE id='".$result['id']."'";
```